# Pause/Resume ActivityGroup's Child Activities?

Tags: android

I have an activitygroup managing a number of child activities.   I
would like to pause/resume child activities when they go off/on the
screen just like they were top-level activities.  How can I do this?
From the documentation it seems as if moving focus from Activity A to
Activity B should pause Activity A, but I am not seeing this
behavior.  The LocalActivityManager source uses ActivityThread, but
this appears not to be exposed for developer usage.

How can I programatically pause/resume an ActivityGroup's child
activity?